# Evaluate $\oint_C\frac{dz}{z-2}$ around the square with vertices $3 \pm 3i, -3 \pm 3i$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I'm having a tough time figuring out $\gamma(t)$ in $\oint_C f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma '(t) dt$. I think I have to split this into four parts, the four separate lines, but from there I'm trying to get things to cancel out so that I could arrive at the answer $2\pi i$. Clearly, we have to consider $3+3i \to -3+3i \to -3 - 3i \to 3-3i$, but I can't seem to find a good starting point.

Comment: Do you have to do it this way? The more obvious solution would be to use Cauchy's integral formula on the function $f = 1$.

Comment: No, I don't have to do it that way, but I don't have much experience with complex integration.

Comment: OK, in that case working with the definition is a good exercise.

Comment: This function isn't analytic though, correct? At $\frac{1}{z-2}$ where $z = 2$, there doesn't exist $f'(z)$. Then, Cauchy's integral formula doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy's integral formula (and the homotopy invariance of the contour integral) tells you that for holomorphic $f$, $$\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-2} = 2\pi i f(2).$$ Apply this to the constant function $f = 1$.

Comment: Since $f = 1$, then $f(2) = f(1513513414124124156757962) = f(-501531351351421412) = 1$? Further, how did you just place $f(z)$ above $z - 2$? What about the original integral told you that is allowed? The fact that it is analytic? Isn't $\frac{1}{z-2}$ not analytic at $z = 2$? I assume it is simply connected though because we could shrink it all down the point $z = 2$? I'm a tad confused.

Comment: @David If it was analytic on all of the interior, then of course we would always get the answer $0$. We can form the integral in any case because $\frac{1}{z-2}$ has no poles on the contour $C$.

Comment: Okay, so it is not analytic, so $\oint_\gamma f(z) \neq 0$. Then, I'm confused how from that we get to $\frac{f(z)}{z-2}$

Comment: @David $f$ is analytic - it's just the constant function $1$...

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm sorry. I was talking about $\frac{1}{z-2}$. However, are we able to just arbitrarily choose what we want to be $f(z)$ and somehow attempt to get the theorem working for it? If so, then I see how we could say $\frac{f(z)}{z-2}$, but then what is said about that? How do we derive $2\pi i f(2)$ from it? Why $f(2)$, and how does that relate at all to the vertices at hand. It seems we haven't talked about them at all.

Comment: @David Yes, the formula holds for any holomorphic $f$. Indeed, the formula doesn't depend on the vertices

Comment: Would the vertices be irrelevant in $\frac{1}{z-51111}$ or $\frac{1}{z-1}$? So, what I should gather from this is that $f$ is analytic, so I could utilize the fact that $\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} = 2\pi i f(\text{any integer I want here})$. Is this correct?

Comment: In particular, $f(\text{any integer I want here})$ only applies for this question because $f = 1$, but if $f = 2z + 4$ and we have $\oint_C\frac{2z+4}{z-2}$, then $2\pi i f(\text{any integer I want here})$ will yield different results, so what would be the appropriate value? $z_0$?

Comment: @David Yes, it would be $z_0$

Comment: Would the vertices be irrelevant in $\frac{1}{z-51111}$ or $\frac{1}{z-1}$?

Comment: I assume they would be relevant because 51111 does not fall inside my square, but 1 does.

Comment: @David The only thing that matters is whether $z_0$ is inside the contour

Answer (score 0):

We have four curves:
$C_1=x-3\cdot i$ for $-3 \leq x \leq 3$
$C_2=3+y\cdot i$ for $-3 \leq y \leq 3$
$C_3=x+3\cdot i$ for $-3 \leq x \leq 3$
$C_4=-3+y\cdot i$ for $-3 \leq y \leq 3$

Then we just have $\int_C f(z)\,dz=\int_{C_1}f(z)\,dz+\int_{C_2}f(z)\,dz+\int_{C_3}f(z)\,dz+\int_{C_4}f(z)\,dz$.

I can add more to clarify.

Comment: From this point though, don't we get 4 solutions, the first one being $\log(3-3i-2) - \log(-3-3i-2)$, which become cumbersome and I don't think they add up to $2\pi i$

Comment: Ah.  Well I just started a Complex course.  We only recently touched on the Cauchy Integration Formula.  Anyway, I dealt with a similar problem, except it was with the unit square.

Comment: It's alright. I got it now. Lots of cool stuff I need to read about in regards to complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the Cauchy Integral formula. And you will get $2\pi(i)f(2)$ = $2\pi(i)$, since $f(z)=1$ and $2$ is an interior point of your contour.

This link should clarify: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

By using the Cauchy integral theorem, one can show that the integral over C (or the closed rectifiable curve) is equal to the same integral taken over an arbitrarily small circle around a. Since f(z) is continuous, we can choose a circle small enough on which f(z) is arbitrarily close to f(a). On the other hand, the integral, [image]

Comment: I know 2 is on the interior because it is within -3 and 3?

Comment: Connect the vertices of your square and you see that z=2 lies within your contour.

Comment: How do we know $f(z) = 1$?

Comment: check above for explanation

Comment: I'm not sure how $\oint_\gamma f(z) = 0$ relates to that.